# Missing Draw Link on Adopt Signature Dialog in Embedded Signing Session

Tags: iframe, cross-browser, html5-canvas, docusignapi

Our implementation of Embedded Signing (aka In-Session, Captive Recipient, etc.) is now discovering yet another undocumented limitation. The document and Agreement dialog are loading correctly in the iframe. On the Adopt Signature dialog, however, there should be both a "Select Style" link and a "Draw" link.  The latter enables the canvas feature for HTML5-compliant browsers for the user to draw their signature on a touch-screen or even using a mouse.

The "Draw" link does not appear when using IE (version 9, 10 or 11) -- and it is completely missing from the DOM. Chrome and Firefox render as expected. My conclusion is that a script to write the tag is not running. Additionally, other screen elements are skewed, as if an html tag is missing its closure or styling scripts have not completed.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I've heard of others encountering issues with some browser types/versions when trying to render the DocuSign signing session within an iFrame.  If you haven't already done so, I'd recommend that you try rendering the DocuSign Signing session within its own browser window/tab (instead of rendering it within an iFrame).  In addition to (hopefully) resolving the IE-specific issues that you're currently experiencing, rendering the DocuSign signing session within its own broswer window/tab also provides a much better user experience on mobile devices (due to the limited amount of screen real estate available).

Comment: We implemented the embedded session in an iframe based on DocuSign recommendations.  There are also many posts on this forum that indicate the iframe is required and that the embedded session will only work in an iframe.  Has that requirement changed?

Comment: An iFrame is absolutely not a requirement. In fact, the DocuSign REST API guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf) specifically recommends against using an iFrame if your app will run on mobile devices. From page 166 of the guide: "Important: DocuSign recommends that you do not use iFrames for embedded operations on 
mobile devices."  To easily test whether it's the iFrame causing your issue in IE (without having to change your code or anything), just (manually) paste the URL that the POST Recipient View response contains in to a new tab in IE.